# why doesn't app.get middleware works after app.use middleware in expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I am using the following code in my server.js file, but the code in get is never running with app.use() middleware but once I comment out the app.use middleware, app.get() middleware is functioning properly. Can someone tell me why this is happening? Here is a snippet of my code-

```
app.use('/',express.static('public'))

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    console.log('get req on /')
    res.send('returned') })
```

Comment: Tried it. Not working

Comment: You dont happen to have an `index.html` file in your static dir do you, as `/` route will look for this.  Also try moving your static after your get, as this is also more performant.

Answer (score 1):

Try `app.use('/', express.static('public', {fallthrough: true}))`
Edit: never mind, looks like fallthrough is the default, so specifying this option won't change the behavior.

Comment: tried it. still not working. I am running the whole express app on a http server so that socket.io can also run on the same server. Does this change anything?

Comment: That just changes how errors are handled.  A file not found in static should go to next route.

Comment: I mean. it is serving the static files in "public" folder. But it should also go the next middleware, i,e app.get(). Shouldn't it. But it is not going. This happens when the next() method is not specified in the middleware. But in express.static() i don't think there is a way to do this. Is there?

Comment: @SaurabhSingh  `app on a http server `  what do you mean here, your express app should be running on its own port.  If you want to mix with something like Apache etc, you will want to look into using a reverse proxy.

Comment: The fallthrough option should cause the static middleware to call next() if a file isn't found. https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static/blob/master/index.js#L107

Comment: earlier it was running on http server, but now even after it is running on its own port, the error persists

Comment: and how to call next() if file is found?

Comment: It won't call next() if the file is found. What would you like to do after a file is served? Calling res.send() again after a static file is served would be bad. You could do something like `res.on('end', () => console.log('res over'))`.

Comment: if file is found you cant call next, you cant have 2 responses in one request.  @TrevorDixon  what I mean is thats the default.  If a file is not found it should go to next route as default.